# Real world definition of the inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us consider an example from the real world: study of food chains, where there is very important determination of spread and accumulation of environmental pollutants in living matter. Suppose that the food chain has three links: The first link consist of vegetation of types $v_1,v_2,\dotsc,v_n$, which provides all the food requirements for herbivores of species $h_1, h_2, \dotsc, h_m$ in the second link. The third link consists of carnivorous animals $c_1, c_2, \dotsc, c_k$, which depend entirely upon the herbivores in the second link for their food supply.

Suppose a matrix

$$A = [a_{ij}] = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
  a_{11} & a_{12} & \dotsb & a_{1m} \\\\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & \dotsb & a_{2m} \\\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
  a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \dotsb & a_{nm}
\end{pmatrix}$$
represents  the total number of plants of type $v_i$ eaten by the herbivores in the species $h_j$, and another matrix
$$ B = [b_{ij}] =
\begin{pmatrix}
  b_{11} & b_{12} & \dotsb & b_{1k} \\\\
  b_{21} & b_{22} & \dotsb & b_{2k} \\\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
  b_{m1} & b_{m2} & \dotsb & b_{mk}
\end{pmatrix}$$
represents the number of herbivores in species $h_i$ which are devoured by the animals of type $c_j$.

My question is what does $A^{-1}$, $(AB)^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ represent?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you at least please *try* to use LaTeX for the math? You've been here for almost a year now and this was *terribly* written. I also took the liberty to fix up your grammar.

Comment: Even after kahen's cosmetics, I'm still not sure what to make of this question; none of the matrices under consideration seem to be square...

Comment: @Kahen i dont know how to format matrix forms

Comment: You might want to use [this](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) to help you with making $\TeX$-ed up matrices...

Comment: i will use it,sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with a supposedly real world example and then let us suppose three hypothetical species only sequentially depending on each other which is not the real world. Therefore it is a tricky business to define what is real or not in these **Modeling** problems. I wouldn't attach tags to problems as such if I were you.

Additionally, you have not finished the problem definition. You gave us three groups of species and two matrices. Should we multiply these or is it a dynamical system representation?

For example, this is what I understand from the relation you are imposing only because the size of the involved variables match: 
$$
v=Ah \quad ,\quad h=Bc \implies v=ABc
$$
where $c,v,h$ are the column vectors consisting $v_i,c_i$ and $h_i$ stacked on top of each other.

But what are the quantities? what is the dimension of say entries of $A$, $\frac{plant}{animal}$? If I multiply $Ah$ the result is the total number of plants eaten by the herbivors and that is not the variable $v$ that you defined in the beginning.

Comment: this problem is taken from Numerical analysis   book,unfortunately,in book there is not any additional information about  this question,no another variables and constants

Comment: @user3196 Is this the exact wording of the book?

Comment: yes    exactly,i couldn't find  solution of this problem,so post here